# 15 APK upload daily limits in Google Play

Tags: google-play

I need to upload almost 25 apps in Google Developer Console, but after the 15th APK upload, I received an error massage

> You have exceeded the daily APK upload limit. Please upload your APK tomorrow.

How do I increase this limit? What should I do?

Comment: What does Google's API website suggest in terms of increasing this quota? Maybe the solution is to just wait for a day...

Comment: I did not find on the site how to increase this limit.

Comment: From what I've read that 15 APK limit is not really documented. I guess it's just a limit they set to prevent the Play Store being spammed and it can't be changed. The real question is why you have 25 APKs to upload and why it has to be done in one day.

Comment: Such an order from a customer. What can I do(

Comment: can't do anything.. According to Google there is no limit on how many you can update but limit on adding new in single day. Faced similar issue and wait it out for 1 day

Comment: anyone knows when is the reset hour?

Comment: reset hour is 12.00 UTC

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this myself and spoke with a Google rep via chat. To paraphrase, there is an upload limit of 15 apk files within 24 hours. But this only applies to the first upload for each app listing.

The thing that got me is that this includes for app listings that are deleted. So, for the sake of argument, if you create 10 new app listings on Google Play and upload apk files for them, and then create 5 apps, upload apks for them and then delete those 5 app listings, you will have hit your 15 apk upload limit even though only 10 of those apk files / app listings are in the store.