# About Google Play Console Daily APK & Bundle Limit

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have needed to publish about 30 apk to Google Play Console. But There was a daily upload apk limit. I didn't know it. I develop my mobil applications on Adobe Air. But today, last day of Adobe Air at Google Play Console for a while. After today, we will be able to update air applications but we won't be able to publish new app.. When is day finish time for Google Play? Or What is mean of Daily Limit? I published 15 apps yesterday. When can i publish new app again?

Google Play Console

You have exceeded the daily APK upload limit. Please upload your APK tomorrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [15 APK upload daily limits in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872860/15-apk-upload-daily-limits-in-google-play)

Comment: we published 15 applications and we exceeded the limit yesterday for those applications were approved. What can we do? We have to publish other 15 new app on store. Because Last day of Adobe Air app's for a while..

Comment: 24 hours from the first upload time.

Answer (score 0):

when you exceeded the daily APK you have to wait for 24h